# Convert Float with decimal to string without decimal Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataformat

Struggling to convert a float 12345678.0 to a string 12345678  Gone through a few different solutions I've found in SO, but can't seem to get to the finish line, the decimal point will not drop.

Here is what I've tried

```
df["variable"]= df["variable"].astype(str)
df["variable"]= df["variable"].astype(int).astype(str)

# old lambda solution 
cols = ['variable']
for col in cols:
   df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x == x else "")

# convert int to string 
df["variable"] = df["variable"].astype(str)
```

Comment: You can use `.astype('Int64')` which will throw an error if you can't convert your Series safely to int, while also allowing you to store `NaN` in that column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```
df['variable'] = df['variable'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore').astype(str)
```

Comment: I see that you write you have tried it before. What was the error you got?

Comment: Since they're checking `if x == x` it's almost certainly because they have `NaN` in the column (which is why all `int` became float in the first place), and you cant `int(np.NaN)`

Comment: @gtomer that solution results in 2nd error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: So we can debug it, please separate it to two lines: df['variable'] = df['variable'].astype(int) and then df['variable'] = df['variable'].astype(str)

Comment: running conversion to int generates this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

Here's your lambda function

```
lambda x: str(int(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Above not working now.Below code worked for me

```
df_bs["Keyword ID"] = df_bs["Keyword ID"].apply(lambda x: str(int(x)) if x==x else x)
```

x==x to bypass np.nan value